# Question about differential forms and delta functions

Tags: differential-forms, complex-geometry, dirac-delta, de-rham-cohomology

EDIT: Related to "[Derivative of a logarithm and Dirac delta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730418/derivative-of-a-logarithm-and-dirac-delta-function)", "[2-dimensional delta function (complex plane)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501443/2-dimensional-delta-function-complex-plane)" and "[How to define a delta function on complex plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370451/how-to-define-a-delta-function-on-complex-plane)".

In a physics paper by [Agaganic (arXiv:0905.3415)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.3415), the author defines a connection of a certain circle bundle over a space as

$$A_{RR} = \sum_{j}q_{j}\frac{d\phi_j}{\phi_j}$$

where $q_{j}$'s are scalars (real numbers), and $\phi_{j}$'s are in fact coordinates parametrizing the ambient space $\mathbb{C}^{N+d}$ in which one embeds a Calabi-Yau 4-fold $X_{4}$ which is the total space of a circle bundle (with connection $A_{RR}$) over a base space which is $X_{3} \times \mathbb{R}$ (here $X_{3}$ is a Calabi-Yau 3-fold).

The specific question I have is far more elementary than the setting of the physical problem. It is claimed that

$$F_{RR} = dA_{RR} = \sum_{j}q_j \omega_j$$

where $\omega_{j} = \delta^2(\phi_j)d\phi_j \wedge d\overline{\phi}_j$ is a 2-form with $\delta$-function support corresponding to $\phi_j = 0$.

What is the reason for the appearance of this delta-function 2-form? I believe it is related to this post: [How to define a delta function on complex plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370451/how-to-define-a-delta-function-on-complex-plane), but I think we're saying the following is true for the $\delta^{2}(\phi_j)$ function introduced in *this* paper.

$$\delta^{2}(z) \stackrel{?}{=} -\overline{\partial}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i z}\right)$$